# DVR card: Streaming audio through BNC connection?

Tags: video-streaming, dvr, audio-streaming, live-broadcast

I would like to live stream video/audio from a source that uses BNC connector out, and I'm having trouble identifying what kind of DVR/video capture card I would need so that I could stream both video and audio from the same channel or the BNC connector.

Apparently the dvr card my client is using has only BNC connectors that somehow have embedded audio along with the video.

I hope I made any sense and I would very much appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Pro and industrial video equipment use BNC connectors instead of the RCA connectors found on consumer gear.  So writing that this equipment has BNC connectors does not clarify at all what kind of video signal is output.

Comment: Basically is there a way to look for a DVR card that can receive audio and video from one BNC connection?

Comment: Some connectors define the signals and interface, e.g. HDMI.  But a generic connector like BNC could be used for a wide variety of signals.  In fact, you have not even determined if the audio+video signal is analog or digital.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, BNC is a connection type not a signal type.  If the BNC connector is the only output, the signal it carries is probably SDI with embedded audio.  If the BNC connector is carrying an analog signal, you can find BNC/RCA adapters at Radio Shack for a couple of bucks.  Not a hard and fast rule but generally if the BNC signal is analog and there is only a single one, it is probably composite video and if there are 3 of them, it is probably component video.  In both cases, the audio will be coming out over some other port.

So to answer your actual question:  If it is an analog signal, the Blackmagic Intensity Pro is probably your cheapest option.  If it is an SDI signal or if you can't figure it out, your best bet is the Blackmagic Studio.